# how can i use riak in windows with VM?

Tags: python, riak

I initialized Riak in a VM and I want use it on Windows in a Python console.

Riak port: 8098, VM host: 192.168.78.128

Windows :

```
from riak import RiakClient, RiakNode


client = RiakClient(protocol='http', host='192.168.78.128', http_port=8098)
bucket = client.bucket_type('visitors').bucket('hits')

bucket.new("one", data={'value':'one'}, content_type="application/json").store()
```

output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "G:/untitled3/riak_.py", line 13, in <module>
     content_type="application/json").store()
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\bucket.py", line 178, in new
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\util.py", line 98, in __get__
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\bucket.py", line 743, in datatype
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\bucket.py", line 675, in get_properties
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\client\transport.py", line 223, in wrapper
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\client\transport.py", line 150, in _with_retries
   File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
     return self.gen.next()
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\pool.py", line 181, in transaction
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\pool.py", line 143, in acquire
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\__init__.py", line 155, in create_resource

   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\transport.py", line 52, in  __init__
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\connection.py", line 72, in _connect
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\util.py", line 98, in __get__
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\feature_detect.py", line 197, in server_version
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\transport.py", line 74, in _server_version
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\transport.py", line 65, in stats
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\resources.py", line 23, in stats_path
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\util.py", line 98, in __get__
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\resources.py", line 222, in riak_kv_wm_stats
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\util.py", line 98, in __get__
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\resources.py", line 258, in resources
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\transport.py", line 95, in get_resources
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\connection.py", line 33, in _request
   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1001, in request
     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1035, in _send_request
     self.endheaders(body)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 997, in endheaders
     self._send_output(message_body)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 850, in _send_output
     self.send(msg)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 812, in send
     self.connect()
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\riak\transports\http\__init__.py", line 42, in connect

   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 793, in connect
     self.timeout, self.source_address)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
     raise err
 socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
 connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
 connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Run netstat in the VM see if 8098 port is listening.

Comment: @cricket_007  this command should work: `netstat -lntp`